# WPF style applies inconsistently

Tags: wpf, styles

I have a targeted WPF style:

```
<Style x:Key="ImgFadeStyle"
       TargetType="Image">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I apply it to some images:

```
<Image Name="imgFirst"
   Grid.Column="0"
   Style="{StaticResource ImgFadeStyle}"
   Source="pack://application:,,,/AppGUI;component/Images/Temp/resultset_first.png"
   ToolTip="First"
   MouseLeftButtonUp="imgFirst_MouseLeftButtonUp" />

<Image Name="imgLast"
   Grid.Column="6"
   Style="{StaticResource ImgFadeStyle}"
   Source="pack://application:,,,/AppGUI;component/Images/Temp/resultset_last.png"
   ToolTip="Last"
   MouseLeftButtonUp="imgLast_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
```

In the codebehind, I set the `IsEnabled` property to "true" or "false".  The first image always reacts as expected.  The second image does not react to the property change.  Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: H.B. is mostly likely right. You can easily verify this using the [WPF Visualizer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/05/25/wpf-visualizer-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx). If you have imgLast in the Watch window after hitting a breakpoint (such as in imgLast_MouseLeftButtonUp), then you can click the magnifying glass. It will list the properties on the right side and it will tell you the source of the Opacity property.

Answer (score 2):

This could possibly be an issue caused by [Dependency Property value precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), if you set the `Opacity` of the last image somewhere explicitly this might override the style's efforts.

Comment: Good thought, but the Opacity is not set in any other location.

Comment: Well, there is no reason of it not to work looking at your code. I'm pretty sure that the context is at fault. Cannot really tell you anything just looking at this.